# Views relationship working back from a content type

Tags: views, 7, nodes

This is a very specific issue with Views Relationships, I essentially want a table view incorporating 3 content types which are linked by an Entity Reference and field collection module. I'm having trouble setting up the relationships so I have drawn a mapped out picture of what it is - and how it should be:

[image]

The content types are "Curriculum", "Observation" and "Students". I can accomplish my table layout if I work from the Observation and include relationships, but I'm unsure how to connect the relationships to work backwards from Curriculum. The view should list all the Curriculum node titles (eg ELG 01 through to ELG 16) - this is why I need to work backwards from this content type and not just list ones that are set in the Observations.

An Observation will allow a user to tag a student (entity ref to Students content type) and it allows you to list a "Curriculum Area" and a "Curriculum Level" (these are grouped under the field collection field_curriculum_area_level.

If I was performing the views from an "Observation" perspective it would look like this:

[image]

But I need to start by listing all the Node Titles from the "Curriculum Areas" and then list the associated "Observations"

This is how the view looks (though the filter should work from "Curriculum" and not "Observation"

[image]

So to recap, I can get a list of "Observations" showing "Students" and "Curriculum" strands that are related, but I can't setup the relationships by starting with a view that starts with "Filter: Content Type: Curriculum Area" - I need to essentially setup relationships to work my way back from these "Curriculum" areas and show the Observation titles and Student Names -- if anyone has any ideas that'll be brilliant.

Cheers,
Garry.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand your problem, you want display a list of "Curriculum" and inside each "Curriculum" show all observation of this item (like your second screen).

If you aren't blocked by add some module to your project, you can try "[views_field_view](https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view)".

In your View, you create a first display who list all your "Observations" filtred by "Curriculum" nid (like your second screen).

Then, you create a second display who list all your "Curriculum" with a View field who use the first display.